# How to get Store label for attribute

Tags: attributes

I am confused. What is the point of that label if I always get Admin label? I want to get Default Store View title. 
I want this title to be displayed for configurable products.
I can get it through `<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('test')->getStoreLabel() ?>` but I still have to see how to get attribute code. Is there any simpler solution to achieve this?[image]

Comment: I don't agree that is a duplicate :) I mean I don't want the entire list and also I am in another context

Answer (score 7, accepted):

please try the below code. with the using of this code you got the attribute Label.

```
// Here you can have whole model of perticular attribute.
$productAttribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attrCode);

// Now you can get it by store or can get all.
$_label = $productAttribute->getStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
echo $_label;
```

Comment: where attribute code $attrCode is? I know what it is ..but how can I get it in my context? I am in configurable.phtml. What I don't get why the things aren't simple like instead of `<?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?>` to have `<?php echo $_attribute->getStoreLabel() ?>`

Comment: I can achieve what I want through `<?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): 
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($_attribute->getAttributeId());?>
        <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $attribute->getStoreLabel() ?></label></dt>` but I wanted something simpler. I mean..why should I load a model to get a label which should have been there....Am I missing something?

Comment: `$attrCode` means for example color is attribute then when you edit the color you can see the attribute code you have to use that attribute code

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I said. I know what is attribute but how can I get there..because that file is used for all configurable attributes, I can't just hardcode 'color'

Comment: so you can fetch the attribute code from id